# django Model got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_id'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, formset, django-4.0

I am trying to create a page with formset in it. So far I've gotten the following:

forms.py

```py
class ContractorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contractor
        fields = [
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'company_name',
        ]
```

views.py

```py
class ContractorUpdateView(SimpleLoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Handle GET requests: instantiate a blank version of the form."""
        ContractorFormSet = formset_factory(
            Contractor)

        contractor_formset = ContractorFormSet()
        context = {"contractor_formset": contractor_formset}
        return render(
            request, "accounts/contractor_form.html", context)
```

contractor_form.html

```html
      <div class="card-body">
        <form class="" method="post" action="" id="facility_contractor_form">
        {% for form in contractor_formset %}
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
        {% endfor %}
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
        <input type="submit" form="facility_contractor_form" value="Save Changes"
               class="btn btn-success float-right">
      </div>
```

But when I try to open the page, I'll get the following error:

```
TypeError at /facility/2/contractor/

Contractor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_id'
```

Any ideas? I think my using `for` maybe the wrong idea

Answer (score 1):

Your ContractorUpdateView references the model, while it should reference the form, so it gotta be:

```
ContractorFormSet = formset_factory(ContractorForm)
```